# React Native: removing the current screen from the navigation stack maintaining the previous screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am building a React Native application. I am using React Navigation, https://reactnavigation.org/ for the navigation. Now, I am struggling the remove the current screen or history of the screen like in native Android.

I tried reseting it like below.

```
 props.navigation.reset({
                            index: 0,
                            routes: [{ name: "ItemDetails" }]
                        })
```

I am invoking that code within the ItemList screen. But landed onto the ItemList screen from HomeScreen. If I use that code, the Home screen is also removed from the stack. But I only want to remove ItemList from the stack and maintain the Home screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: author specified that he wants to go to another page after removing current one from the stack.

Stack based navigators in `react-navigation` have `replace()` method, which will remove current screen from stack and go to arbitrary route (or "replace" current route) - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#replace

If you want just to go back instead, `goBack()` will remove current screen from stack and go to previous screen. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#goback

Comment: No I am not trying to go back. I am trying to go to another page but remove the current screen from the history.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then what you are looking for is `replace()` method on `StackActions` object. Stack navigators have it - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/#replace